# Error: expected expression & expected unqualifed-id

Tags: c++

I'm building an application that does a thing... Ya boi's trying to implement a password feature that allows the user to *create a password* if they're a new user, or *enter their password* if they're a returning user (all data being written/read to and from a txt file named UserData.txt), and the compiler keeps returning the errors listed below. I've looked all over Google to no avail and I'm thinking that maybe it has something to do with the `Password` variable declaring a string, but I don't know why it's expecting an expression if that's the case. I'm fairly new to coding so the code's a bit sloppy but here it is along with the errors I can't seem to figure out:

**CODE:**

main.cpp

```
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "math.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include "Privacy/Password.hpp"
    
    using namespace std;
    
    //Variable Prototypes
    
    //Function Prototypes
    void display();
    void CreatePassword();
    
    
    //Main Function
    int main()
    {
      cout << "\t\t\t~~Welcome to Tegridy Pharmaceuticals!~~" << endl;
      CreatePassword();
    }
```

Password.hpp

```
    #include <iomanip>
    #include "math.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::ofstream;
    using std::ifstream;
    using std::fstream;
    using std::string;
    
    
    //header call 
    #ifndef Password
    #define Password
    
    //ProtoTypes
    
    
    //variables
    string OldPassword = "OldPassword";
    string Password = "OldPassword";
    string PasswordTemp = "";
    
    
    void CreatePassword()
    {
      fstream UserData;
      UserData.open("UserData.txt");
      UserData >> Password;
      
      if (OldPassword != Password)
      { 
        cout << "\nEnter your Password (Case Sensitive):  ";
        cin >> PasswordTemp;
        while (PasswordTemp != Password)
        {
          cout << "WRONG!!! Try Again Dawggy: ";
          cin >> PasswordTemp;
        }
      }
      else 
      {
        ofstream UserData;
        UserData.open("UserData.txt");
    
        cout << "\nCreate Your Password (Case Sensitive)" << std::endl;
        
        cout << "NEW PASSWORD: ";
        cin >> Password;
        UserData << Password " = Password";
        UserData.close();
      }  
    }
    
    #endif
```

**ERRORS:**

```
./Privacy/Password.hpp:25:17: error: expected unqualified-id
string Password = " ";
                ^

./Privacy/Password.hpp:33:23: error: expected expression
  UserData >> Password;
                      ^
                      
./Privacy/Password.hpp:35:30: error: expected expression
  if (OldPassword != Password) 
                             ^
                   
./Privacy/Password.hpp:39:36: error: expected expression
    while (PasswordTemp != Password) 
                                   ^

./Privacy/Password.hpp:53:20: error: expected expression
    cin >> Password;
                   ^
```

Comment: Think a second what the preprocessor will do with seeing something like `#define Password` and `string Password = "OldPassword";` in a single pass. Everything clear?

Comment: yeah I see where you're going with that. XD thanks for the help

Comment: When I make include guards I make sure that I use a name I would never use otherwise for example I would use something like:  `PASSWORD_H` instead of `Password`

Comment: duly noted; thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro definition

```
    #define Password
```

means that any token `Password` in your code after that should be replaced with empty string.

Therefore, it is preventing you from using the identifier `Password` as an variable.

You should give another name to the include guard.

Comment: Wow im so clueless. Thanks for your help!